# Is there a way to find a duplicate per column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got this example data (Dataset_Z) set:

```
|-----------------|------------------|------------------|
|     Type        |     Ref          |       No         |
|-----------------|------------------|------------------|
|      A          |     Lorem        |        1         |
|-----------------|------------------|------------------|
|      B          |     Lorem        |        2         |
|-----------------|------------------|------------------|
|      B          |     Amet         |        3         |
|-----------------|------------------|------------------|
|      A          |     Amet         |        4         |
|-----------------|------------------|------------------|
|      B          |     dicta        |        5         |
|-----------------|------------------|------------------|
|      B          |     dicta        |        6         |
|-----------------|------------------|------------------|
|      A          |     dicta        |        7         |
|-----------------|------------------|------------------|
|      B          |     ullam        |        8         |
|-----------------|------------------|------------------|
|      B          |     ullam        |        9         | 
|-----------------|------------------|------------------|
|      A          |     Velit        |        10        |
|-----------------|------------------|------------------|
|      A          |     Dolor        |        11        |
|-----------------|------------------|------------------|
|      B          |     Ipsum        |        12        |
|-----------------|------------------|------------------|
|      A          |     Sit          |        13        |
|-----------------|------------------|------------------|
|      B          |     Qui          |        14        |
|-----------------|------------------|------------------|
|      B          |   Dolorem        |        15        |
|-----------------|------------------|------------------|
|      A          |   Aliquid        |        16        |
|-----------------|------------------|------------------|
```

I want to find where the instances of all A and B duplicates.

I've tried the below but it doesn't retrieve the duplicates.

```sql
SELECT
    Col_1, Col_2, COUNT(*)
FROM
    Dataset_Z
GROUP BY
    Col_1, Col_2
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 1
```

What I want to achieve is to have all duplicate reference belonging to Type.A and Type.B

Comment: This should return all pairs of a/b values that have duplicates.  What do you want returned?

Comment: If you have (well) formatted tabular formatted text, please do *not* replace it with an image.

Comment: what is your desired output

Comment: Yep, that query does the job. What is the problem?

Comment: This should give you two rows: `B, dicta, 2` and `B, ullam, 2`. What did you want instead? Are you seeing something different? Are you wanting all of the duplicated rows, with the `Col 3` values?

Comment: I don't think I explained it clearly. I've changed the datasets column names FYI. What I want to achieve is to have all duplicate reference belonging to Type.A and Type.B

Comment: @Dez-LuanPieterse Can you add your expected output please?

Answer (score 0):

By retrieve the duplicates it seems you might also require Col_3 to be returned by the query?  If so some something like this could be what you're looking for

```
with dupes_cte(Col_1, Col_2, Col_3, rn) as (
    select *, row_number() over (partition by Col_1, Col_2 order by Col_3) rn
    from Dataset_Z)
select Col_1, Col_2, Col_3
from dupes_cte
where rn>1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually might have figured it out:

```
    SELECT
    Ref, COUNT(Ref)
FROM
    Dataset_Z
GROUP BY
    Ref
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell from the question and comments, you would like to find all References (lorem, ipsum, etc) that have rows with different values for Type?

In the following extract of your data

```
Type Ref    No
--------------
B    Amet   3
A    Amet   4
B    dicta  5
B    dicta  6
A    dicta  7
B    ullam  8
B    ullam  9
```

- Amet should show, because it has both A and B values
- dicta should show, because it has both A and B values (although it has 2 Bs)
- ullam should *not* show, because it only has Bs

If the above is correct, then simply doing a count (as per your answer) will pick up 'ullum' (as it has duplicate values, but both are type B)

However, a simple update is to use COUNT(DISTINCT...) which counts unique values rather than just the number of them.

```
SELECT
    [Ref], COUNT(DISTINCT [Type]) AS NumTypes
FROM
    Dataset_Z
GROUP BY
    [Ref]
HAVING 
    COUNT(DISTINCT [Type]) > 1;
```